# Angularjs Image loaded event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello every one I have Angularjs code which loads an image when a check box is clicked.

code Html1 - where check boxes are rendered

```
    <li ng-repeat="Dep in oDep" >
    <input  type="checkbox" ng- model="cboxDepState[Dep.num]" 
ng-change="OnDepStateChange(Dep.num,Dep.nom)" />

</li>
```

code HTML2 - this is the loader image.

```
<div bg data-ng-show="loading['ville']" class="text-center ng-hide">
<img src="" />
</div>
```

Code AngularsJS

```
var app = angular
             .module("HomeModule", [])
             .controller("HomeController", function (){
              $scope.loading =[];

 $scope.OnDepStateChange = function (numDep, nom) {              
               $scope.loading['ville'] = true;
               //code inside function take 5 second
               //
                $scope.loading['ville'] = false;
}});
```

All the code work fine just loading image  does not   work 
can you help me plz.

Comment: It's not clear at this point - from your explanation and code sample - what the exact problem is. Please revise your question and include a verifiable example in code or in description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give angular some breathing space inside the long function. Use $timeout to execute your lengthy code. Hide the loader inside that function when finished.

```
$scope.OnDepStateChange = function (numDep, nom) {              
      $scope.loading['ville'] = true;

       $timeout(function(){
            //code inside function take 5 second
            //

            $scope.loading['ville'] = false; 
       })         
})
```